# How to fill Nan based on multiple condition?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have data frame like this:

```
       a    b    c
    0  €9K €78M €96M
    1  €0  €0   NaN
    2  €0  €0   NaN
    3  €0  €1K  NaN
```

I want to fill the NaN based on the value in ['a'] and ['b'] like this:

```
1) if df[['a','b']=="€0" then fill df['c] with '€0' when it's NaN
2) if df['a'] == '€0' & df['b'] =="€1k" then fill df['c] with '€1K' when it's NaN
```

I have tried to apply couple thinks I saw on stack overflow but I didn't success.

```py
condition1=[(df['a'] =="€0") & (df['b'] =="€0") ]
condition2=[(df['a'] =="€0") & (df['b'] =="€1K") ]

for row in df['c']:
    if condition1 == True:
        df['c].fillna('€0', inplace=True)
    elif condition2 == True:
        df['c'].fillna('€1k', inplace=True)
    else:
        df['c']
```

so it should looks like this:

```
   a    b    c
0  €9K €78M €96M
1  €0  €0   €0
2  €0  €0   €0
3  €0  €1K  €1K
```

Ps: I know that there is a lot of post on this subject but it didn't work so that why I am posting my problem

Comment: You're not using `row` in your loop.

Comment: the logic isn't clear and I'm don't believe €0  and €1K are the only possible values in your columns. Please explain how this will work for other values as well.

Comment: €0 and €1K are not the only possible values my columns but I just want to focus the attention on that.

Answer (score 0):

We can using `numpy` `select`

```
condition1=(df['a'] =="€0") & (df['b'] =="€0") 
condition2=(df['a'] =="€0") & (df['b'] =="€1K") 
df.c=np.select([condition1,condition2],[df.a,df.b],default=df.c)
df
     a     b     c
0  €9K  €78M  €96M
1   €0    €0    €0
2   €0    €0    €0
3   €0   €1K   €1K
```